# C# Func <> argument types

Tags: c#, string, func

> Im trying "Func" delegation.

```
    Func<int, string[], bool>(myFunc); //works OK
    Func<string[], bool>(myFunc); //Exception ???
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: 
>       Object of 'System.String'cannot be converted to type 'System.String[]'.
>       Looks like "Func" doesn't like argument type "string[]" ?!?"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, Delegate> commandHash = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
            commandHash.Add("Test", new Func<string[], bool>(Test));
            string[] str = { "justtext" };

            try
            {

                commandHash["Test"].DynamicInvoke(str);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception");
            }

        }
        static  bool Test(string[] s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");

            return true;
        }
    }
}


// CODE which works OK, what Im missing ?!

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, Delegate> commandHash = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
            commandHash.Add("Test", new Func<string[], int, bool>(Test));
            string[] str = { "justtext" };

            try
            {

                commandHash["Test"].DynamicInvoke(str, 1);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception");
            }

        }
        static  bool Test(string[] s, int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No; it means you're trying an invalid cast.  Look at the stack trace

Comment: myFunc(string{} s), but it's failing with delegate.

Comment: bool myFunc(string[] s)  //makes Func fail

Comment: I think my cast is OK, single argument type 'string[]'

Comment: Please post code that demonstrate the exception. Code in current sample can't even compile, so there is no way to see why you are getting run-time exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamicInvoke parameter uses the **params object[]** definition.

This means when you are passing an array of string[] to this function, each entry in the array of strings is a new parameter.

You are getting an exception because you cant cast a string to string[];

What you need to do is call DynamicInvoke like this.

```
commandHash["Test"].DynamicInvoke(new object[] { str });
```